# nestjs injectable() not working with extended class

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection, nestjs

hi i'm working on nestjs project recently. I want to use extended injectable service, but some parameters comes out with undefined.

this is my base service code.

```js
@Injectable()
export class TransactionService implements TransactionServiceInterface {
  private readonly workerType: string;

  public constructor(
    protected configService: ConfigService,
    protected logger: CustomLoggerService,
    protected sqsService: SqsService,
  ) {
    this.workerType = this.configService.get<string>('workerType');
  }
```

this is my extended service code.

```js
@Injectable()
export class UserTransactionService extends TransactionService implements TransactionServiceInterface {
  constructor(
    protected configService: ConfigService,
    protected logger: CustomLoggerService,
    protected sqsService: SqsService,
    public userWalletTransactionRepository: UserWalletTransactionRepository,
    public userWalletRepository: UserWalletRepository,
  ) {
    super(configService, logger, sqsService);
  }

// makes error when i try to use userWalletTransactionRepository
```

my module looks like this.

```js
@Module({
  imports: [SqsModule, WalletModule],
  providers: [
    ConfigService,
    SqsService,
    CustomLoggerService,
    TransactionListener,
    TransactionHandler,
    WalletService,
    TransactionService,
    AdminWalletTransactionRepository,
    AdminWalletCollectTransactionMapRepository,
    UserWalletTransactionRepository,
  ],
})
export class TransactionModule {}
```

I tried to put UserTransactionService instead of TransactionService to module, but it doesn't seems to work.
I also tried using `@Inject()` to userWalletTransactionRepository in UserTransactionService. Doesn't work either.

Is there any suggestions?

Comment: What's the error you're receiving?

Comment: i've lost the error message, but what i remember was cannot run repository's method becuz repository is undefined

Comment: Without a stack trace, and possibly more context, I don't think there's enough here to answer your question